# Exporting plots to eps from R does not work with certain fonts

Tags: r, ggplot2, export

I am making some plots for a paper that I would like to export from RStudio as eps files. 
Naturally I would like the legends, axis labels, headers etc. of the plots to be in the same font as that which is used in the paper itself. One example of a plot I'd like to export is this:

```
p<-ggplot(MPY, aes(phiu, phipi, fill= output)) + geom_tile()+
scale_fill_gradient(trans="log",low="gray10", high="gray88", name="sd(y)", breaks=exp(brks2), labels=round(exp(brks2),digits=5), guide="legend") + 
theme_minimal()  + 
xlab("u") + 
ylab("\u03C0") +
theme(text=element_text(family="serif"))
```

If I try to export this as an eps the result is simply a blank file (it can be exported as jpg, pdf, png etc. without problem so there is no issue with the plot itself).

When trying to export using the postscript command I get the warning "Warning message: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,: family 'serif' not included in postscript() device"

Hence the problem is clearly with the font I am trying to use and indeed when removing the line

```
theme(text=element_text(family="serif"))
```

from the above then the plot exports to eps without a problem, but not with the font that I want. How can I get a plot with the right font to be exported to eps correctly?

UPDATE:

I thought I had found what might be a solution to the problem.
Trying

```
font.add("times", regular = "times.ttf", bold = "timesbd.ttf")
showtext.auto()

setEPS()
postscript("test.eps")
par(family = "times")
plot(rnorm(100), main = "Test Font")
dev.off()
```

does indeed produce a graph with the correct font. However, trying the same using the plot I would like to export, i.e.

```
font.add("times", regular = "times.ttf", bold = "timesbd.ttf")
showtext.auto()

setEPS()
postscript("test.eps")
par(family = "times")
p<-ggplot(MPY, aes(phiu, phipi, fill= output)) + geom_tile()+
scale_fill_gradient(trans="log",low="gray10", high="gray88", name="sd(y)", breaks=exp(brks2), labels=round(exp(brks2),digits=5), guide="legend") + 
theme_minimal()  + 
xlab("u") + 
ylab("\u03C0")
dev.off()
```

again just produces a blank file.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10.

I should also add that even when using

```postscript(file="plot.eps",fonts = "serif") ```

The result is a blank file. I am also using the extrafont package and "loadfonts(device = "win")" at the beginning of my script.